# Is there any free multi purpose development server?

Tags: continuous-integration, statistics, development-environment, collaboration

There are so many tools out there. You can do so much things around developing that it is a full time job on its own. So why not integrating features / tools to an powerful server application.

Is there a server which integrates (some of) these features:

- static code analysis
- automated builds (e.g. through maven)
- continuious integreation
- automated tests
- project website (source code, team collaboration, documentation, java doc)
- bug tracking
- version control (e.g. through SVN)
- statistics
- download section
- code coverage
- any other metrics and quality supporting features

I am sure there are more useful features which do not come to my mind right now. There are tools out there supporting one or the other feature.

Is there any software that supports some more of those features? It would be perfect if that software would be free, but at least it should be non commercial. I am mostly using Java.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you want Cruise Control or Hudson.  Both can do most of the items on your laundry list.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a setup for [Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org), Maven, [Nexus Repository Manager](http://nexus.sonatype.org/) and a Bug Tracking Tool like Redmine. The Redmine can be started with a [Bitnami Stack](http://bitnami.org/stack/redmine) which includes Subversion.

The code analysis can be done by using cobertura, findbugs etc. with Maven (using Plugins). If you need more metrics take a look at [sonar](http://www.sonarsource.org/) with support of a Maven Plugin.

The Web-Site etc. can be done by using Maven (site generation).

Answer (score 0):

I like Launchpad...

Launchpad is a software collaboration platform that provides:

- Bug tracking
- Code hosting using Bazaar Code reviews
- Ubuntu package building
- Hosting Translations
- Mailing lists
- Answer tracking and FAQs
- Specification tracking

[Take the tour!](https://launchpad.net/+tour)
The key is the package building. You should check it out.

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement is "[Ff]ree" I'd suggest Hudson.  It's quite modern and has a ton of plugins that can take care of the requirements you've asked for.  Hudson is *very* actively maintained and the plugins receive lots of attention too.

- Homepage here:  http://hudson-ci.org/
- List of plugins here:  http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Plugins
- IRC Channel (great resource for help):  [irc://chat.freenode.net/#hudson](http://irc://chat.freenode.net/#hudson)

Hudson literally takes minutes to setup and bootstrap as well, in simple cases.

Comment: +1 for Hudson. There's a plugin for everything, and it's easy to setup and maintain. With Build Slaves and a *free form* build it's possible to build almost every job you can dream of.

Answer (score 0):

You can get exactly everything you need in one package, and free, in [fazend.com](http://www.fazend.com). The platform integrates SVN, Trac, CruiseControl, Maven, etc. You start a project with one click.